# Is there any way to convert a YMD_HMS to only Number of Minutes? (R)

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have this dataset [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VQDM.png). As you can see, the ride_length column is in YMD HMS format, and it is supposed to be the time elapsed between start_time and end_time.
Is there any way to convert this into num of minutes for arithmetic calculations?

I have tried formatting as.numeric `trips_df$ride_length <- as.numeric(trips_df$ride_length)` but the resulting column isn't right. This is my first R project so I don't know a lot of stuff, I am exploring on the way.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: `difftime(trips_df$end_time, trips_df$start_time, units = "min")`. I don't know what "differencing" you did, but none of the `diff`-variants with which I'm familiar return a `POSIXt` (timestamp) object like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the difference. If your objects are not in class `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"` you can cast them with `as.POSIXct`.
Using toy data since no data is posted.

```
start_time <- Sys.time(); system('sleep 2'); end_time <- Sys.time()

end_time - start_time
Time difference of 2.017358 secs

class(start_time)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

##### Arithmetic operations

```
( end_time - start_time ) * 10
Time difference of 20.17358 secs
```